# Cache based globalization in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, globalization

I have an MVC 3 application with all texts in a SQL database. The texts has names and values for each language. I want to store the texts in cache object and somehow get them in my views and in my controllers based on some session variables.

My first solution has been to store an object TextHandler in the Cache. TextHandler has all texts and methods to help extracting texts by their name (as a string) and by some other values. I also have some controller methods and helpers to get texts from TextHandler based on session variables. I'm not satisfied by this solution.

I've found some guides for this, but what I really need are some pointers on how to do it and not actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a custom resource provider like http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2010/06/25/extending-resource-provider-for-soring-resources-in-the-database.aspx with minor modifications.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you could store them in an in-memory cache (either distributed or local depending on how many languages and dictionary values you have).

You could use a languagecode|name key and the value is the word in that language.

so you can have us|header_name as the key and "My Header" as the value for example.

As I mentioned above where these values can be stored depends on your requirements. If you think that they don't belong in the local memory you could always setup either a memcache structure or an LRU cache that holds the top N most popular values that get used a lot and if there is a cache miss it goes to the database (that contains your dictionary in all languages) to find the value given then name and language.

Hope this helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

A common way is to supply the code on the url and used as a parameter in the controller. This language code is then used in addition to whatever string you are querying in the database.

If you would consider resource files, the solution is already set for you:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

The other thing is based on what the browser requests set the culture. use this name to query the database. The culture name (from [How to pass CultureInfo to partialView for ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343547/how-to-pass-cultureinfo-to-partialview-for-ajax-call))

```
public static string GetCurrentCulture()
{
   return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
}
```

Now to go cache specific, simply implement the repository pattern. When you query by 'language' and 'string' check to see if that exists in the cache. If it is, return it, otherwise go to the database to retrieve it. This is a great advantage of using the Repository Pattern, the cache details are removed from the caller. If you decide to go to a resource file implementation, then none of this is required anyways since there is built in culture support.